# Code that download empty file and supposed not to

Tags: java

I have this part of function where it supposed to download file like pdf from server and store in new directory. It does do this but an empty pdf or text file.How to fix it.

```
 `File urlfile = new File(host + "/" + path);
            urlfile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            // create outputstream for request and inputstream for data
            // download

            FileOutputStream outS = new FileOutputStream(urlfile);
            DataInputStream instream = new DataInputStream(newsocket.getInputStream());

            // get rid of head part to get to actual file
            String l = null;
            String lastmodtime = null;
            boolean done = false;
            while (!(l = DAA.readLine()).equals("")) {

                if (!done && l.contains("Last-Modified:")) {
                    lastmodtime = l.substring(l.indexOf(' ') + 1, l.length());
                    done = true;
                    System.out.println(l);
                }
            }

            // read in bytes to correct file name
            try {
                byte[] inbytes = new byte[16384];
                int input;
                while ((input = instream.read(inbytes)) != -1) {
                    outS.write(inbytes, 0, input);

                 }
             }`
```

Comment: this does not compile.

Comment: okay, where is the bug tho?

Comment: you are right. it doesn't go into the try and the loop so there is nothing going to be written. Can you tell me what should I do

Comment: You should accurately describe the problem you're having, not what the code is supposed to do

Comment: basically, I need to download a file from from url and save in in my cache. However, my code downloads the file, dir and pictures from the url but the pdf or the text saved with same name but empty papers nothing written in them.

Comment: This code does not download a file because this code does not even compile.  Whatever code you are running that's creating empty files is not this code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this simple code if you want to create a copy of the file or you can even use apache commons io (`FileUtils.copyFile(source, dest)`) for java copy file operation.

```
private static void copyFileUsingStream(File source, File dest)
            throws IOException {
        InputStream is = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(source);
            os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } finally {
            is.close();
            os.close();
        }
    }
```